# pop up of edge in ie mode getting blocked running from selenium script though the pop up are disabled in both edge and IE browsers

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer

I am trying to run selenium automation scripts in edge in ie mode and it's blocking all the pop ups though they are disabled in the settings both in edge and ie.

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. I test Edge IE mode with selenium automation, it can open popup windows successfully. How do you disable the settings? Could you please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce** the issue? We can't locate the issue with only the above simple text description.